# drools arraylist collect access object

Tags: drools

How do I access access a getter from an item ArrayList which is the result of collect in Drools 5.5?

In code similar to the sample below, I get `The method getStatus() is undefined for the type Object`.

I've tried casting the result, I tried generics `ArrayList<Alarm>`.

At the end of the day, I'm trying to access two items in `ArrayList()`.

```
rule "Raise priority if system has more than 3 pending alarms"
when
    $system : System()
    $alarms : ArrayList( size >= 3 )
              from collect( Alarm( system == $system, status == 'pending' ) )
then
    System.out.println($alarms.get(0)); // show Alarm.toString() 
    System.out.println($alarms.get(0).getClass()); // prints "Alarm"
    System.out.println($alarms.get(0).getStatus());

   // Raise priority, because system $system has
   // 3 or more alarms pending. The pending alarms
   // are $alarms.
end
```

Comment: Duh! Cast

System.out.println(((Alarm)$alarms.get(0)).getStatus());

Comment: In the rules Drools does not support generics: http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-How-to-handle-generics-in-Drools-td3427723.html